# Not able to install Shiny Server

Tags: permissions, gdebi

Following instructions [here](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/) to install Shiny server, encountered error - `Failed to open the software package` as below.

```
> sudo gdebi shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
Failed to open the software package
The package might be corrupted or you are not allowed to open the file. Check the permissions of the file.
```

**Permissions**

```
> ls -al
total 83140
drwxr-x---  3 tom users     4096 Mar 16 07:23 .
drwxrwx--x  5 tom users     4096 Mar 16 08:26 ..
drwxr-x--- 27 tom users    24576 Feb 12 07:48 ruby-2.4.0
-rw-r-----  1 tom users 14104044 Dec 25 04:30 ruby-2.4.0.tar.gz
-rw-r-----  1 tom users 70643942 Feb 25 03:23 shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb
>
```

**without sudo**

```
> gdebi shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
Building data structures... Done

Shiny Server
 Shiny Server is a server program from RStudio, Inc. that makes Shiny applications available over the web. Shiny is a web application framework for the R statistical computation language.
Need to be root to install packages
>
```

**update - with dpkg**

```
> sudo dpkg -i shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb
dpkg-split: error: unable to read part file `shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb': Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb
>
```

Comment: what about `sudo dpkg -i shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb` ?

Comment: Also all my `.deb` have as permissions `-rw-rw-r--` (664)

Comment: @bistoco - updated the post with info.

Comment: according to [this](https://dailies.rstudio.com/shinyserver/ubuntu/), the command `md5sum shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb` should give you `b150199aca4442bdb50be4c8d96d42e7`. If the value is different, the file is corrupted and the actual error is the part `The package might be corrupted`

Comment: @bistoco  according to the official Rstudio download server page,  the md5 should be `515b16075999eef3bc49b87863aa938c ` which is what is seen with   the downloaded package as well `> md5sum shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb
515b16075999eef3bc49b87863aa938c  shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb`    https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/

Comment: `sudo chmod 0664 shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb && sudo gdebi shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb` ??

Comment: @bistoco  `> sudo chmod 0664 shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb
Enter password for tom (INTRANETPASS) :
chmod: changing permissions of ‘shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb’: Operation not permitted
>`

Comment: As well as the .deb not being readable by others (including root), the parent directory is not writable or executable (openable) by others (including root) - `chmod` **as `tom`** should work however `gdebi` may still have problems with your strange directory permissions.

Comment: @steeldriver - `chmod` as tom did work and the package was successfully installed.

Answer (score 1):

Got this fixed by chmod as non sudo user due to particular permissions setting in this enterprise machine.

```
> chmod 0664 shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb
> ls -al
total 83140
drwxr-x---  3 tom users     4096 Mar 16 07:23 .
drwxrwx--x  5 tom users     4096 Mar 16 08:26 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 tom users 70643942 Feb 25 03:23 shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb
>

> sudo gdebi shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb
Enter password for tom (INTRANETPASS):
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
Building data structures... Done

Shiny Server
 Shiny Server is a server program from RStudio, Inc. that makes Shiny applications available over the web. Shiny is a web application framework for the R statistical computation language.
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
Selecting previously unselected package shiny-server.
(Reading database ... 81902 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack shiny-server-1.5.3.838-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking shiny-server (1.5.3.838) ...
Setting up shiny-server (1.5.3.838) ...
Creating user shiny
Adding LANG to /etc/init/shiny-server.conf, setting to en_US.UTF-8
shiny-server start/running, process 8854
>
```

credits - cues from @steeldriver, @bistoco